# How do I deserialize this JSON into C# objects

Tags: c#, json

I have the following JSON and class structure but I cannot figure out how to deserialize it into the objects.

The classes were automatically generated from the josn by https://app.quicktype.io/

The JSON was returned by an REST API.

```
{
"last_executed_prices": {
    "9707645": [
        {
            "contract_id": "33837223",
            "last_executed_price": "79.37",
            "timestamp": "2020-03-04T14:33:14.711040Z"
        },
        {
            "contract_id": "33837246",
            "last_executed_price": "3.85",
            "timestamp": "2020-03-04T14:31:58.158066Z"
        },
        {
            "contract_id": "33837219",
            "last_executed_price": "36.5",
            "timestamp": "2020-03-04T14:33:10.361513Z"
        }
    ],
    "999567": [
        {
            "contract_id": "33837223",
            "last_executed_price": "79.37",
            "timestamp": "2020-03-04T14:33:14.711040Z"
        },
        {
            "contract_id": "33837246",
            "last_executed_price": "3.85",
            "timestamp": "2020-03-04T14:31:58.158066Z"
        },

        {
            "contract_id": "33837248",
            "last_executed_price": "7.69",
            "timestamp": "2020-03-04T14:32:41.560315Z"
        },
        {
            "contract_id": "33837220",
            "last_executed_price": "4.17",
            "timestamp": "2020-03-04T14:32:39.898192Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

And this is the class structure:

```
    public partial class LastExecutedPrices
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<LastExecutedPrice>> LastExecutedPricesLastExecutedPrices { get; set; }
}

public partial class LastExecutedPrice
{
    public long ContractId { get; set; }
    public string LastExecutedPriceLastExecutedPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried the following but just get a null object

```
LastExecutedPrices data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LastExecutedPrices>(badjson);
```

Comment: Your property names don't match. `last_executed_prices` is not the same as `LastExecutedPricesLastExecutedPrices`.

Comment: Altered the class structure to this - same result - null object     public partial class 'LastExecutedPrice
    {
        public long ContractId { get; set; }
        public string Last_Executed_Price { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
    }'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```cs
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("last_executed_prices")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<LastExecutedPrice>> LastExecutedPrices { get; set; }
}

public partial class LastExecutedPrice
{
    [JsonProperty("contract_id")]
    public long ContractId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_executed_price")]
    public string LastExecutedPriceLastExecutedPrice { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for which you have to create another class is that your JSON is an object that contains a field called last_executed_prices that is a dictionary that associates a string to a list of LastExecutedPrice.

For the ContractId Property, you should change it to a string type because in your JSON it is surrounded by double-quotes, so it will be deserialized to a string. If you want to have it translated to an int, you have to do add a converter.

**UPDATE**: You can also declare the ContractId property as long. Newtonsoft.JSON is capable of deserializing the strings in the JSON into a long if that string is a valid number that can be parsed into an Int64.

You can easily test my solution by adding this:

```cs
string json = @"{
    'last_executed_prices': {
        '9707645': [
            {
                'contract_id': '33837223',
                'last_executed_price': '79.37',
                'timestamp': '2020-03-04T14:33:14.711040Z'
            },
            {
                'contract_id': '33837246',
                'last_executed_price': '3.85',
                'timestamp': '2020-03-04T14:31:58.158066Z'
            },
            {
                'contract_id': '33837219',
                'last_executed_price': '36.5',
                'timestamp': '2020-03-04T14:33:10.361513Z'
            }
        ],
        '999567': [
            {
                'contract_id': '33837223',
                'last_executed_price': '79.37',
                'timestamp': '2020-03-04T14:33:14.711040Z'
            },
            {
                'contract_id': '33837246',
                'last_executed_price': '3.85',
                'timestamp': '2020-03-04T14:31:58.158066Z'
            },

            {
                'contract_id': '33837248',
                'last_executed_price': '7.69',
                'timestamp': '2020-03-04T14:32:41.560315Z'
            },
            {
                'contract_id': '33837220',
                'last_executed_price': '4.17',
                'timestamp': '2020-03-04T14:32:39.898192Z'
            }
        ]
    }
}";

Root obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

After the deserialization, you should have a valid object containing the dictionary that associates strings to List of LastExecutedPrice.

I hope my solution will be useful, let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Thank you - I think I've just got to same point by altered the names as suggested

Comment: The name was not the only problem. The first problem was the structure of the json returned from the API and your class structure. With my solution, you can resolve both problems.